# Asp.new web app to direct user to client or staff member page according to the type of user which is registered in the data base of the system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-authorization

I really need help with this situation I am having right now
[Distribution picture for the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jy2w.jpg)

I used to program websites using the conventional PHP a while back but now I have to shift to Asp.net MVC which I am new to and having a huge troubles to understand it but i have to make a simple Asp.net MVC 6 and Entity Framework 7 website as simple as displaying a login form in the home page to login as a client or staff member or register as a client 
so when a user logs in the system is suppose to detect that if he is a staff member or a client and direct him to the staff member page or client page according to his role which is registered in the database

Comment: When user logs in, you get the user id from the username. Check your table(s) to see what type of member that user is. According to that, redirect to corresponding page. Did you try to do that ?

Comment: Your question is a bit too openended for us to help with.  Shyju's comment is the correct approach but it sounds like you are having troubles standing up the application.  I'd recommend watching a few of the Microsoft intro videos.  I watched several of them when I first started learning C# MVC and they cleared up a lot of confusion.